# Activity not changing - crash

Tags: android, mobile, error-handling

I get an error when I am trying to change activity. It used to work but I don't know what has happened.

I looked on line 25 but I don't see what's wrong. Am I doing something wrong?

```
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-105
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MainActivity }
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
02-07 20:05:02.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.example.quizapp.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:25)
```

This is my Splash.java class:

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import com.example.quizapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.MainActivity");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this code

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.MainActivity");
```

with this one

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Also be sure you have declared your MainActivity in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.quizapp;
```

This is your package.

You need to reference your whole class + package name:

```
 Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(
                        "com.example.quizapp.MainActivity");
```